# Import csv file to Hadoop Hive table without schema

Tags: mysql, csv, hadoop, hive

I want to import csv file without providing its header or datatype information in Hive metastore.

Someone suggested load data into a Hive directly from the db using Sqoop without defining table in Hive by:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://db.foo.com/corp --table EMPLOYEES --hive-import
```

However, each row of the table may have different number of columns, and also I would like to search the whole table afterwards. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're importing this from MySQL, how do you have a different number of columns per row?

Comment: It's actually more like a log file.